# is `std::map<..> a; blah = a[abcd];` thread safe if abcd was not created before this call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, dictionary, std

So we created a map. We want to get `some_type blah = map_variable[some_not_inserted_yet_value]` this would call add new item to map if one was not previosly created. So I wonder if read is really thread safe with `std::map` or it is only possible to thread safly `try{ ...find(..)->second...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea that calling `find(...)->second` is thread-safe is very dependent of your view of thread-safety. If you simply mean that it won't crash, then as long as no one is mutating the dictionary at the same time you're reading it, I suppose you're okay.

That said, indeed, no matter what your minimum thread safety requirements are, calling the `operator[]` method is inherently **not** thread-safe as it can mutate the collection.

If a method has no `const` overload, it means it can mutate the object, so unless the documentation indicates methods are thread-safe, the method is very unlikely to be.

Then again, a `const` method might not be thread-safe as well, because your object could depend on non-`const` global state or have `mutable` fields, so you'll want to be very, very careful if you use unsynchronized classes as if they were.

Answer (score 2):

If you're 100% sure that the map contains the key, then it is *technically* thread-safe if all other threads are also only invoking read-only methods on the map.  Note however, that there is no `const` version of `map<k,v>::operator[](const k&)`.

The correct way to access the map in a thread-safe fashion is indeed:

```
map<k,v>::const_iterator match = mymap.find(key);
if ( match != mymap.end() ) {
    // found item.
}
```

As stated before, this only applies if **all concurrent access is read-only**.  One way this can be guaranteed is to use a [readers-writers lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock).

Note that in C++03, there is no mention of threads in the standard, so even that is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.  Make sure to check your implementation's documentation.

Comment: How can you say that's the correct way to access the map in a thread-safe fashion? How do you know there are no a concurrent write operations that can displace the end iterator?

Comment: @Kabumbus, in C++03, the standard didn't even acknowledge threads, so a question such as yours doesn't make sense (in regard of the standard). In C++11, threads are acknowledged, but what you're asking for is specified to be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Emile: I specified "if all other threads are also only invoking read-only methods on the map".  This can be ensured by your application.

Comment: @Andre: It's not obvious that the "all other threads are read-only" condition still applies to your second paragraph. It won't let me undo the downvote until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Standard library containers have no notion of thread safety. You have to synchronize concurrent read/write access to the container yourself.

`try` has nothing to do with multithreading. It's used for exception handling.

`find` does not throw an exception if the key is not found. If the key is not found, find returns the map's `end()` iterator.

Comment: I think he thought `find` threw an exception when it didn't find the item, I don't think it was being used for thread safety.

Comment: try has nothing to do with multithreading - I agree but in case of find(..)->second not exists error will be thrown and we would have to create new what ever we were searching for, fill it with data lock the mutex and insert new data into map.

Comment: @Kabumbus According to [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) `find` it doesn't throw an exception but returns `std::map::end` when the item doesn't exist.

Comment: Calling `->second` on `end` results in undefined behavior. As is the case for dereferecing any container's `end` iterator.

Comment: @Kabumbus why would you? Compare the iterator returned by `find` to `std::map::end` and if it compares false, use `second`, else don't because it's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `operator[]` is not "thread safe" because it can mutate the container. You should use the `find` method and compare the result to `std::map::end` to see if it found the item. (Also notice that `find` has a `const` version while `operator[]` does not).

Like others have said, the version of C++ before C++11 has no notion of threads or thread safety. However, you can feel safe using `find` without synchronization because it doesn't change the container, so it's only doing read operations (unless you have a weird implementation, so make sure to check the docs). As with most containers, reading from it from different threads won't cause any harm, however writing to it might.

Comment: You can't "feel safe using `find` without synchronization" if there's the possibility of a concurrent write operation.

Comment: @Emile if you say so I believe you, but why is this? What could happen if you use `find` while some other thread is writing to the container? And why did you not also downvote Andre's answer since it's also "wrong"?

Comment: I did downvote Andre's answer. :-) Using find like you suggest is not thread safe because it is not an atomic operation. A concurrent write operation will disturb the internal state of the map without `find` knowing about it. For example, what if a node that `find` is walking through is suddenly deleted?